# Crystal Report export issues

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with 45 fields, i was added fields in single text field because i want to export crystal report in to plain text format, but whenever i export to plain text it show only 197 character in single line but i want all 350 characters in same line. So i was use Crystal Report 10 to run report and it gives correct output. I have DNN portal and i was put that rpt on portal that uses crystal report (version 10.2) dll, but whenever i trying to run that report again it show only 197 characters in single line but i want all 350 characters in same line. So what should i need to do, plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of testing in this area a few years ago and found that v10 allowed the widest exports, but v11 can go up to 600 characters if you do it just right. The two main factors are the width of the object and the "Characters Per Inch" setting used during export. Try making the text object 20 inches wide, and when you export set the CPI to 26.  If you can do those you should get all of your characters.  The only part of this I don't have experience with is the DNN portal, which might introduce some other unknown issues.